# MySQL - How to test user variable and use it in DROP VIEW

Tags: mysql, variables, null, prepared-statement, group-concat

I'm new to user variables in MySQL and have run into some errors when trying to use them for anything but a SELECT statement. I'm trying to run a batch job to delete temporary views that are created in my database. The process is:

Step 1: identify the temporary views and put the list in a variable.

Step 2: test the variable to see if it is null

Step 3: drop the views

Issue 1: the drop is not working, even if I don't test for null. I receive this message: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 13: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@VIEWLIST_PRE' at line 1

Issue 2: the null test is not working when included. I receive this error: mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 12: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF(@VIEWLIST_PRE IS NULL) THEN
        DROP VIEW @VIEWLIST_PRE' at line 1

Below is the code. How must this be written to work? I really appreciate the help! Thank you!!

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 18446744073709551615;

-- Get the PreSummary views
SET @VIEWLIST_PRE = (SELECT
                    CONCAT(
                        GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME)
                    ) AS stmt
                    FROM information_schema.TABLES
                    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "raptor" AND TABLE_NAME LIKE "%Pre%");

SELECT @VIEWLIST_PRE; -- THIS WORKS!
IF(@VIEWLIST_PRE IS NULL) THEN  -- BREAKS
    DROP VIEW @VIEWLIST_PRE;  -- BREAKS
END IF;
```

*** SOLUTION ***

I tweaked Used_By_Already's solution (only [one command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371677/execute-multiple-semi-colon-separated-query-using-mysql-prepared-statement) can be executed at a time in a prepared statement, from what I gather). Here's the final code for the bulk DROP:

```
SET @VIEWLIST_PRE = (SELECT
                    CONCAT(
                        GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME)
                    ) AS stmt
                    FROM information_schema.TABLES
                    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "raptor" AND TABLE_NAME LIKE "%Pre%");
SET @DROP_VIEW_PRE = CONCAT('DROP VIEW IF EXISTS ', @VIEWLIST_PRE);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @DROP_VIEW_PRE;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

A good question was raised about why a targeted drop is not being used. The reason is that it's not executing successfully from PHP, but no error was received.  However, after much searching, I found the issue and can now do the targeted drop.

Comment: I see the aggregation method **GROUP_CONCAT()** but no **GROUP BY** clause, you sure that **GROUP_CONCAT()** have sense?

Comment: Why are you creating "temporary views"?  Seems like an odd thing to do. In addition you would need to form "dynamic sql" to use variables **as** SQL.

Comment: The code works in gathering a list of views (I took it from another stack overflow post).  The views are generated by separate code, not posted, in the creation of pivot tables for reports. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked Used_By_Already's solution (only [one command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371677/execute-multiple-semi-colon-separated-query-using-mysql-prepared-statement) can be executed at a time in a prepared statement, from what I gather). Here's the final code for the bulk DROP:

```
SET @VIEWLIST_PRE = (SELECT
                    CONCAT(
                        GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME)
                    ) AS stmt
                    FROM information_schema.TABLES
                    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "raptor" AND TABLE_NAME LIKE "%Pre%");
SET @DROP_VIEW_PRE = CONCAT('DROP VIEW IF EXISTS ', @VIEWLIST_PRE);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @DROP_VIEW_PRE;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

A good question was raised about why a targeted drop is not being used. The reason is that it was not executing successfully from PHP, but no error was received.  However, after much searching, I found the issue and can now do the targeted drop.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure why or how you create these temporary views, but instead of attempting some bulk clean-up on a regular basis, why not just use:

```
drop view IF EXISTS some_view_name;
```

Just prior to the code you currently use to create each temporary view.

This way it will not matter if the view exists or not.

---

If you are going to proceed with what looks like a bulk clean-up then the query would need to look more like this:

```
SET @VIEWLIST_PRE = (concat((select group_concat(concat('drop view if exists ',table_name) SEPARATOR '; ')  
                             from information_schema.views 
                             where table_schema = 'raptor' and table_name  like'%Pre%')
                            ,';'))
```

then the generated string would look like this:

```
drop view if exists Pre1; drop view if exists Pre2;
```

Then you need to use a `prepared statement` to execute that generated SQL. You CANNOT just include a user variable AS a string of SQL code as a query.

See: [MySQL Prepared Sattement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: Thank you! I will try that.

Comment: Used_By_Already - with a little tweaking of your solution (I'll post above), I was able to get the bulk drop to work. To elaborate on the reason I'm using the bulk drop instead of a targeted drop (which would be cleaner): a) the views are generated by executing MySQL form PHP. b) the drop is not working from PHP, but I'm also not receiving an error code. When I copy/paste an echo of the command from PHP into MySQL Workbench, the code executes perfectly in MySQL. Thus, I'm unable to locate the issue. Therefore, the bulk drop is a hack, but something I can get to work.

Comment: One more consideration - how do I test for an empty / null user variable? I don't want to execute the command if there is nothing to drop. Thanks again - I appreciate it!