# Multiple insert queries using Prepared-Statement in MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I want to run multi-insert in MySQL stored procedure using prepared statements. Here is my query:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `insertMult`(IN insertStatement VARCHAR(999999))
BEGIN

SET @t1 =CONCAT("INSERT into sga.errorData(roundId, userId, errorType, description, createdOn)values(1,11,'custom','cusErr','2020-01-01') INSERT into sga.errorData(roundId, userId, errorType, description, createdOn)values(1,11,'custom','cusErr','2020-01-01')");

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @t1;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END
```

But when I run it, I got error;

> Error : 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO sga.errorData(roundId, userId,
>   errorType, description, createdOn)val' at line 1

it runs perfectly fine, when there's only one insert like this;

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `insertMult`(IN insertStatement VARCHAR(999999))
BEGIN

SET @t1 =CONCAT("INSERT into sga.errorData(roundId, userId, errorType, description, createdOn)values(1,11,'custom','cusErr','2020-01-01')");

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @t1;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END
```

> It also runs fine when I simply run multiple inserts instead of prepared statements. I don't know why is it not working with multiple inserts in Prepared statements. Any guesses?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute multiple semi-colon separated query using mysql Prepared Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371677/execute-multiple-semi-colon-separated-query-using-mysql-prepared-statement)

Comment: well it didn't.. but yes it gave me idea to solve my issue.. I don't know I should post that idea as answer here or delete my question..