# Assign Query String in a variable

Tags: mysql, sql

In mySQL stored procedure how can I assign a Query String to a variable, so I can reuse it? In my example I will be using `SELECT id FROM audit` many times.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc() 
BEGIN

UPDATE person SET status='Active' WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM audit);

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT id FROM audit);

//Multile scenarios the `SELECT id FROM audit` will be used.

END
```

Something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc() 
BEGIN
myVariable = SELECT id FROM audit;
UPDATE person SET status='Active' WHERE id = (myVariable;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (myVariable);

//Multile scenarios the `SELECT id FROM audit` will be used.

END
```

Comment: Use the subquery.  I don't see any issue with that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff there were multiple time i will use that subquery. Im thinking it to assign to a variable so if I edit that subquery, i will only just edit once.

Comment: does `audit` contain a single row and does this change during the procedure execution?

Comment: If you want a query to be executed once and reuse the resultset then use temp tables. OR if you are trying to keep the SQL query (in string format ) in a variable, you need to run it dynamically. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371677/execute-multiple-semi-colon-separated-query-using-mysql-prepared-statement/20374657#20374657

Comment: It makes no sense. The query will be parsed and executed each time when you use it. If you want to reuse its output then store it into temporary table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? Sorry I am not sure what you need.

```
    SELECT @myCount:= count(id)  FROM audit;
    select @myCount;
```

Based on your reply, do you need a temporary table to store the ids from the audit and re-use those on the queries?

```
create temporary table tbl_tmp_audit;
select id from audit;
```

I am assuming you need this so that you won't join the whole audit columns every time on your succeeding queries.

```
--first query
UPDATE person AS p
INNER JOIN tbl_tmp_audit t ON p.id = t.id
SET status = 'Active';
--second query
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_tmp_audit;

Drop temporary table tbl_temp_bookings;
```

Comment: its something like: myVariable = SELECT id FROM audit;  

UPDATE person SET status='Active' WHERE id = (myVariable);

Comment: i edited my code. and put some example

Comment: @average.joe, i edited my reply