# Run a query foreach databases (mysql)

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a straight way to run a query on all databases hosted on my mysql server.

I have a bunch of Magento installations and I want to truncate all Magento log table on all databases:

- log_customer
- log_visitor
- log_visitor_info
- log_url
- log_url_info
- log_quote
- report_viewed_product_index
- report_compared_product_index
- report_event
- catalog_compare_item

I think it something very easy to accomplish in mysql but I cannot find a straight answer/solution.

**UPDATE **
According to @Ollie Jones it is not possible to do it without a STORE PROCEDURE or a server side language ( PHP or whatever )

**UPDATE 1**
I choose to follow the PHP approach (@samitha) for 2 reasons:

1. STORE PROCEDURE looks more complicated
2. Query on 'information_schema' table is very slow ( at least if you have many DB/TABLES)

Comment: Do you know the Magento database names? because i might know an way to solve it as an pure MySQL approach

Comment: `information_schema' queries should be very fast indeed. If they are not, something is seriously wrong with your MySQL server.

Comment: I have 20gb of DB ... could it be the reason ?

Comment: following query takes 91sec for me `SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE  '%PJ_%'
AND TABLE_NAME LIKE  '%log%'`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
  SELECT DISTINCT SCHEMA_NAME AS `database`
    FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA
   WHERE  SCHEMA_NAME NOT IN ('information_schema', 'performance_schema', 'mysql')
   ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME
```

gets you a list of all the non-MYSQL databases on your system.

```
  SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA AS `database`,
         TABLE_NAME AS `table`
    FROM information_schema.TABLES
   WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
   ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
```

gets you a list of all the actual tables (excluding SYSTEM VIEWs like the `TABLES` table, and user-defined views) in all the databases.

Then, you should implement logic in your program to ensure that, for each database, it really is a Magento database before you truncate certain tables. Otherwise, you might become a despised person among your co-workers. :-)

**Edit**

Here's a stored procedure.

You need to edit it to do exactly what you need it to do; in particular, it counts rows rather than truncating tables, and it doesn't contain the correct list of log tables. (It would be irresponsible for me to publish such a wildly destructive stored procedure; you should edit it yourself to do the destructive part.)

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `zap_magento_logs`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `zap_magento_logs`()
BEGIN

    -- declare variables for database and table names
    DECLARE dbname VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE tbname VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT '';

    DECLARE done INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

    -- declare cursor for list of log tables
    DECLARE log_table_list CURSOR FOR 
      SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA AS `database`,
             TABLE_NAME AS `table`
        FROM `information_schema`.TABLES
       WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
         AND TABLE_NAME IN 
         (
            'log_customer',
        'log_visitor',
        'log_visitor_info',
        'log_url',
        'log_url_info',
        'log_quote'
         )
       ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME;

    -- declare NOT FOUND handler
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN log_table_list;

    log_table: LOOP

        FETCH log_table_list INTO dbname, tbname;

        IF done = 1 THEN
        LEAVE log_table;
        END IF;

        -- create an appropriate text string for a DDL or other SQL statement
        SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM  ',dbname,'.',tbname);
        PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
    END LOOP    log_table;
    CLOSE log_table_list;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

You run this by issuing the SQL command

```
  CALL zap_magento_logs();
```

Comment: can you expand your answer ... what should I do at this point ? how to loop on all the result a truncate the wanted tables ?
it is my local developed environment :)

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'database FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME LIMIT 0, ' at line 1

Comment: @WonderLand Anything you write may make it into production!

Comment: @samitha oops, forgot to escape reserved words. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @OllieJones is there any way to unselected certain databases using onlysql ?

Comment: To do this in pure MySQL without the help of a host language is going to require a stored procedure. This is because DDL (such as TRUNCATE) can't be mixed with DML outside stored procedures.

Comment: @samitha what do you mean "unselect certain databases" ?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, my mysql knowledge is not very rich :) if it is not a big deal please share the store procedure approach

Comment: Ex: i have 7 databases in my server.I don't want to select 4 of them.Can only using mysql?

Comment: what about something similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575419/how-can-i-truncate-multiple-tables-in-mysql

Comment: Well, OK, here is a stored procedure. I hesitate to give you this because it contains multiple levels of MySQL concepts with which you may not be familiar, and I am not a believer in simply teaching people "magic spells."

Answer (score 7):

I didn't feel like writing code to solve this so I found a different solution.  I wrote SQL that generates the SQL that I need.  So I saved the following to a file called createSomeSQL.sql:

```
SET sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT';

select 
'truncate table ' || dbs.database || '.someLogTable;'
 as ''
from  (SELECT DISTINCT SCHEMA_NAME AS `database`
         FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA
        WHERE SCHEMA_NAME NOT IN ('information_schema', 'performance_schema', 'mysql', 'test')
        ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME) as dbs;
```

You could replace the SQL in line 4 with anything you want. Then I ran this command to generate the SQL that I need:

```
mysql -u root -p < createSomeSQL.sql > sqlToExecute.sql
```

Replace "root" with your username, of course.  Now the file sqlToExecute.sql contains a script you can run to execute that SQL against all your databases.

Comment: I think this is the simplest answer and the best one!

Comment: We have an identical database for each client. Using Ryan's script as a basis, we added user accounts with privileges using ```SELECT CONCAT("GRANT DELETE,INSERT,SELECT,UPDATE ON `",TABLE_SCHEMA, "`.* TO 'someuser'@'%';") FROM information_schema.TABLES
   WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME = 'a_table_in_all_similar_databases'
   ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA  ;```

Comment: is that set mode a permanent change to the database that could produce side effects in existing applications?

Comment: @Brad No, it's only for this session. Quit the Mysql command line and restart it and you'll have to run it again. Every session starts with the default.

Answer (score 6):

A PHP approach would be:

```
$tables = array(
    'log_customer',
    'log_visitor',
    'log_visitor_info',
    'log_url',
    'log_url_info',
    'log_quote',
    'report_viewed_product_index',
    'report_compared_product_index',
    'report_event',
    'catalog_compare_item',
);

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
));


$sql = $dbh->query('SHOW DATABASES');
$getAllDbs = $sql->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($getAllDbs as $DB) {  

        foreach ($tables as $table) {
            $dbh->query('TRUNCATE TABLE ' . $DB['Database'] . '.' . $table);

    };
};
```

Comment: finally this is easier and faster

Comment: ohh Cool.Yeah.I'm doing this with 45 databases of my server.Please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (very basic, no error handling, may not work at all, I've not tested this):

```
$db = mysqli_connect(); // your database connection

$tables = ["log_customer", "log_visitor", "log_visitor_info"]; // array with all the tables

foreach ($tables as $table) {
    mysqli_query($db, "TRUNCATE TABLE `".$table."`"); // executes query for each element in the array
}
```